# Flatten a nested dictionary and convert it into columns of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON which I converted into a dictionary and trying to make a dataframe out of it. the problem is that it is multiple nested and with inconsistent data

For e.g.

```
d = """[
      {
        "id": 51,
        "kits": [
            {
                "id": 57,
                "kit": "KIT1182A",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 254,
                        "product": {
                            "name": "Plastic Pallet",
                            "short_code": "PP001",
                            "priceperunit": 2500,
                            "volumetric_weight": 21.34
                        },
                        "quantity": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 258,
                        "product": {
                            "name": "Separator Sheet",
                            "short_code": "FSS001",
                            "priceperunit": 170,
                            "volumetric_weight": 0.9
                        },
                        "quantity": 18
                    }
                ],
                "quantity": 5
            },                                     #end of kit
            {
                "id": 58,
                "kit": "KIT1182B",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 259,
                        "product": {
                            "name": "Plastic Pallet",
                            "short_code": "PP001",
                            "priceperunit": 2500,
                            "volumetric_weight": 21.34
                        },
                        "quantity": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 260,
                        "product": {
                            "name": "Plastic Sidewall",
                            "short_code": "PS001",
                            "priceperunit": 1250,
                            "volumetric_weight": 16.1
                        },
                        "quantity": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 261,
                        "product": {
                            "name": "Plastic Lid",
                            "short_code": "PL001",
                            "priceperunit": 1250,
                            "volumetric_weight": 9.7
                        },
                        "quantity": 5
                    }
                   
                ],
                "quantity": 7
            }                                    #end of kit
        ],
        "warehouse": "Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1",
        "receiver_client": "Lumax Cornaglia Auto Tech Private Limited",
        "transport_by": "Kiran Roadways",
        "transaction_type": "Return",
        "transaction_date": "2020-08-13T04:34:11.678000Z",
        "transaction_no": 1180,
        "is_delivered": false,
        "driver_name": "__________",
        "driver_number": "__________",
        "lr_number": 0,
        "vehicle_number": "__________",
        "freight_charges": 0,
        "vehicle_type": "Part Load",
        "remarks": "0",
        "flow": 36,
        "owner": 2
    } ]"""
```

I want to convert it into a dataframe like the following:

```
transaction_no  is_delivered    flow    transaction_date    receiver_client warehouse   kits    quantity    product1    quantity1   product2    quantity2   product3    quantity3
1180       False    36  2020-08-13T04:34:11.678000Z Lumax Cornaglia Auto Tech Private Limited   Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  KIT1182A    5   PP001   5   FSS001  18  NaN NaN
1180       False    36  2020-08-13T04:34:11.678000Z Lumax Cornaglia Auto Tech Private Limited   Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  KIT1182B    7   PP001   5   PS001   5   PL001   7.0
```

or to show it in a better way:

[image]

What I have done:

```
data = json.loads(d)
result_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
l = ['transaction_no', 'is_delivered','flow', 'transaction_date', 'receiver_client', 'warehouse','kits']  #fields that I need
result_dataframe = result_dataframe[l]
result_dataframe.to_csv("out.csv")
```

I tried :

```
def flatten(input_dict, separator='_', prefix=''):
output_dict = {}
for key, value in input_dict.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict) and value:
        deeper = flatten(value, separator, prefix+key+separator)
        output_dict.update({key2: val2 for key2, val2 in deeper.items()})
    elif isinstance(value, list) and value:
        for index, sublist in enumerate(value, start=1):
            if isinstance(sublist, dict) and sublist:
                deeper = flatten(sublist, separator, prefix+key+separator+str(index)+separator)
                output_dict.update({key2: val2 for key2, val2 in deeper.items()})
            else:
                output_dict[prefix+key+separator+str(index)] = value
    else:
        output_dict[prefix+key] = value
return output_dict
```

But it gives all the values in a single row, how can I seprate them on the basis of kits and get the result?

Answer (score 3):

Pandas [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize) function should be what you are looking for.

Here is how to normalize your Json input:

```py
pd.json_normalize(data, ['kits', 'items'], 
                  [['kits', 'kit'], 'transaction_no', 'is_delivered','flow', 'transaction_date', 'receiver_client', 'warehouse'], 
                  errors='ignore', record_prefix='kits.')
```

- First argument is your dataset
- Second argument is the record path,
  the level of nested data you want in your input
- Third argument is the
  path to meta datas you want to add to your input

According to having products splited by columns, you should try to do a pivot table.

Good luck.